# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.5

Tags: scala, jackson, apache-kafka, jackson-databind

I know this has been asked before but i got following error and i need to upgrade the jackson related jar due to vulnerabilities scan

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.5
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
            ... 12 more
```

My build.gradle as follw

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
}

 compileOnly "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.0.cloudera1"
    compileOnly "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.5@jar"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.5@jar"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5@jar"
```

Any idea which version of spark streaming i need to use in order to use jackson-databind 2.9.5 ?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by updating the jackson module scala module 2.11 to 2.9.5 version

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, Align your Jacson.module.scala version with your Scala version...
In my case, jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.9.5 has fixes the issue.